# Input Box moves to Next Line

Tags: html, css, input

I need a little help. I am coding html/css from a PSD. It involves custom inputs. [Here is the link for your reference.](http://annaswardrobe.net/double_linx/search_doublelinx.html)

When you select any option from the drop down and then click on the input box which is in parallel to it (Seller Name), it automatically moves down. I do not know whats causing the issue...

Comment: What web browser are you using that you see this issue with?

Comment: issue not coming in IE10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a vertical align top and it works like a charm ;)

```
.styled-select-search {
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet reset.css change to:

```
Line #15: vertical-align: top;
```

Or set a new div with equivalent:

```
div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```